# How to set Grails Log4J to only log info level from the app

Tags: grails, configuration, log4j

I have log4j set up to a basic level in my grails 2.4.2 app. It prints out to console/writes to a file whenever there are error level logs. Now I want to go back and set it up to log info level logs from my app as well. My config looks like below:

```html
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    appenders {
        environments {
            production {
                rollingFile name: "stacktrace", maxFileSize: "10MB", maxBackupIndex:2,
                        file:"/tmp/logs/stacktrace.log"
            }
        }
    }

    info 'grails.app'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate',
            'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

}
```

The problem is, when I set root up to log info level logs as well, I get info logs written out from all of grails dependencies. This makes it impossible to tail and track down anything off info logs. Is it possible to just print out the info logs of the grails app, and keep only printing error logs from dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to just print out the info logs of the grails app, and
> keep only printing error logs from dependencies?

Yes.  You could configure each logger individually if you wanted.

I expect the issue you are having is related to `info 'grails.app'` which is configuring too many loggers.  If you extend that prefix you can narrow down the affected loggers.  For example, if you wanted to configure your controllers, you could do something like `info 'grails.app.controllers'`.  You could be more specific if you wanted and do something like `info 'grails.app.controllers.com.yourcompany'`, etc.  You can do the same for whatever artifact types you want to configure.